# Loading the stdin buffer

Tags: c, buffer, stdin

I have a function that calls `fgets()` with `stdin` as stream, looking for user input. However, there are some cases in which I would rather have the program decide what is entered rather than asking for user input. If I could find a way to load the `stdin` buffer with the value before calling the function with `fgets()`, would that allow me to not alter the function that contains `fgets()` while still taking program input? If so, how would one load the `stdin` buffer?

Comment: You would like to push some characters onto the `stdin` buffer, correct? Including the end of line character?

Comment: Yeah. I think that should work. How would you do that?

Comment: Why don't you just concatenate the strings after you call `fgets()`?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to automate the user input?

Comment: Yeah, automating the user input to `fget()` for certain cases would be helpful. I figured that might be doable by loading the buffer before calling `fgets()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a cool trick you might enjoy trying:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char myString[100];
  char *hello = "hello world\n";
  int ii;
  for(ii=strlen(hello); ii>=0; ii--) ungetc(hello[ii], stdin);
  fgets(myString, 99, stdin);
  printf("I just read '%s'\n", myString);
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run, I get:

```
I just read 'hello world
'
```

Note that the `newline` remained with the string (it was necessary for `fgets` to return immediately) - so you need to take care of that separately. There was no need for me to hit a carriage return separately - just run the program.

I'm sure you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the number of possible succesful calls to `ungetc()` is limited: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ungetc.html

Comment: @alk - tha is for mentioning that, and for the link. Not clear what the limit is - I suppose you need to look at the return value to confirm success or failure for each byte. That does leave this solution very brittle...

Comment: The limit is slightly confusing. The `ungetc()` page linked above clearly states _One byte of push-back shall be provided_, but the description of the function otherwise describes push-back in the plural. (Additionally, when I learned of this function, I learned of it as having an explicit one byte limit.)

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer but it doesn't involve the std buffer.  In some programs that I've written, I've had optional command line parameters.  You could add a command line flag and include optional input either in the command line or as an input text file.  I can expand on this answer if this option suits you.

Comment: I'd thought of that, but I wanted to see if there was a more "clever" way to do it, so to speak.